# Does addition of properties to conf object available back in driver ?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My MR job is acquired as follows :

```
Job job = new Job(conf, "helloWorld");
```

Any values set on the `conf` are available across the nodes. But I'm not sure whether the following will work or not :

**in MAP**

```
conf.set("hello", "world");
```

**in Driver**

```
if( job.waitForCompletion(true) ){
     System.out.println(conf.get("hello"));
}
```

Will the modifications made to `conf` during map/reduce phase be visible in the driver ?

Comment: Interesting question! Did you try that and did not work? What would happen if each mapper set a different value? Maybe you could use MultipleOutput to store those values and retrieve them from the Driver.

Comment: I tested it few minutes back and found out the answer you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit a job, you also provide the Configuration, as you said:

```
Job job = new Job(conf, "helloWorld");
```

This is a call by value in Java (see [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/2516301) for example).

What would happen if many mappers set different values to `hello`?

I believe that the functionality you are looking for, is [MultipleOutputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html). 
Write the desired values in some new files, which you can read from the Driver, using hadoop's FileSystem, when the task is finished.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now, I'm gonna try `DistributedCache` to handle it if possible, since only few KBs of data required back in the driver.